# Using data values rather than percentages for gradient stops

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gradient

I did a lot of searching and could not find an answer and hence stuck. I just wish to know whether it was possible to define gradient stops from our data rather than percentages. As my graph changes each time with user input.

I even tried using for example, the following but still no changes.

```
  .data([
        { offset: "0%", color: "#B81B1B" },
        { offset: function (d) { return d.yaxisvalue[5]; }, color: "#B81B1B" },
        { offset: function (d) { return d.yaxisvalue[5]; }, color: "#4294DE" },
        { offset: "100%", color: "#15992A" }
 ])

**Update**
```

[image]

I have added an image of the graph that I would like to plot using the gradient. So as you can see I want the gradient to change whenever the y value matches the x axis value at 5 , 2 and 1. This plot changes based on the user input. Hence the 5, 2 and 1 are never in the same position. So is there a way I can convert the positions into percentages to use them in the gradient or do I create 3 separate area paths with specified colors ?

I have included the vertical gridlines as I thought it would be clear to understand.

Comment: No you can't, but you can quite easily compute the percentage with the current and maximum values.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff : I tried out a formula but apparently just one colour appeared. Would this idea be right ( (current value / maximum value) *100) ?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. Did you check that your data is what you expect though? From the sample you've posted, it looks like `d.price[5]` shouldn't work.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: I could not put the code in the comment section so updated the original post. i tried using "offset: (pricestring[5] / maxval) * 100". Is there another way to represent the  value because for my needs they are fixed as areas between (max value and 5, 5 & 2 and the rest) ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If you're asking whether you can compute the percentage of a fixed maximum, then yes, certainly.

Comment: For example i want the region from the starting point till the point ( pricestring = 5) to be colored red. I tried "offset: ((5 / maxval) * 100)" and "offset: (pricestring[5] / maxval) * 100" but it just doesnt work.

Comment: For that you need to count the number of points until that value and the total number of points rather than considering the values themselves.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Would you have any link or example that I could refer to ?

Comment: It would be easier if you could post a complete, reproducible example with an exact description of what you're looking for.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff : I updated by creating what the plot would look like. I have been reading else where and I came to know that we could create separate paths but I am not able to find a code example for it.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff : I tried a lot but just cannot find a way to colour the graph based on percentages. I have updated my question to include a how the final plot should look like. Again, Thanks for all your time and help.

Comment: Here's an example that may help: http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/2Tebe/